# How can I find out how many capturing brackets are in a Perl regexp?

Tags: regex, perl

If I am given a [regexp](/questions/tagged/regexp) in Perl, can I find out how many capturing brackets there are?
So, for example:

```
\w       -> 0
(\w)     -> 1
(\w(\w)) -> 2
```

Comment: It would help if you could tell us why you need this information - i.e. what are you going to use it for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two special array @- and @+ containing the start positions 
and the end positions of successful matches. Use the array length
when matching is done.

Static analysis: To know all pairs you need to parse the regex string.
Count all unescaped opening bracktes which have a closing one.

Comment: Unescaped opening brackets WITHOUT a "?:" following them, as (?:text) doesn't capture.

Comment: Using the @- array is gives me the info I want.

Comment: Rather late to accept the anwser. When I posted I was new to SO and hadn't worked out accepting posts.

Comment: "Count all unescaped opening bracktes which have a closing one." -  Actually this is not completely valid. Think of `(?:...)` which is a non-capturing bracket by definition. Or `(?#...)`, `(?{...})`, `(*PRUNE)` (and many more) in newer regexps. To really find almost all capturing groups `use re 'Debug', 'DUMP';` can be used (see my [finding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41743435/how-can-i-detect-how-many-capture-groups-are-in-a-perl-regexp)).

Answer (score 4):

Do you want to know how many matches there are or how many sets of brackets? If you want to be able to count the brackets then you might want to take a look at a module like [Text::Balanced](http://search.cpan.org/~dconway/Text-Balanced-v2.0.0/lib/Text/Balanced.pm) which parses delimited text.

On the other hand, if you want to know how matches there are you would be better off executing your regular expression in list context:

```
my @matches = $string_to_match_on =~ /(\w(\w))/;
```

The size of the list will give you the number of matches:

```
my $count = @matches;
```

(as a list or array in scalar context gives the size of the list or array).

Comment: I am trying to find out the number of captures (possible matches).
I am wary of trying to count brackets as becuse of edge cases like 
"\\(" or [(]

Comment: The I think you probably need a 'proper' parser such as Text::Balanced or you could throw caution to wind and write one using Parse::RecDescent. You are right that counting brackets is unlikely to work much of the time. Are you dealing with regular expressions as input to your code?

Answer (score 2):

It is important to know why you need this.

Does [YAPE::Regex](http://search.cpan.org/~pinyan/YAPE-Regex-3.03/) help?

**Edit:** Here is demonstration:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;
use YAPE::Regex;

my $regex = qr/^(A)(B)(C)[0-9]+(\w+)$/;

my $parser = YAPE::Regex->new($regex);

my $n_captures;

while (my $node = $parser->next) {
    if ( $parser->state =~ /^capture\(([0-9]+)\)$/ ) {
        $n_captures = $1;
    }
}

print "$n_captures\n";


C:\Temp> t
4
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not really trivial as not all parentheses are not capturing - for example (?:...), (?=...) and so on.

Generally, remember you can always:

```
my @catch_all = $string =~ m/......................./;
```

and then just check @catch_all;

Comment: If I do that, how do I tell the difference between a regexp with no captures and match failing.

Comment: If that matches fails, the empty list is always returned.  If the match succeeds, the list will contain the single number '1' if there are no capturing parentheses.

Depending upon what you're doing, you may also find named captures useful.  There's a Perl-tip on them at http://perltraining.com.au/tips/2008-02-08.html